# Can I use my Mac's speakers and AirPlay / Bluetooth at the same time?

Tags: mac, audio, airport, bluetooth, airplay

I have an iMac at my home office that I'm often playing music on from the output speakers. I also have an AirPort Express with a speaker connectable to via AirPlay / Bluetooth. I was wondering, is there any way to play my music from the standard output on my iMac, and at the same time, play it from my AirPort Express using AirPlay or Bluetooth?

**Reference:**

iMac 27" Late 2013 running OS X 10.11.3

AirPort Express Dual-band 802.11n

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using iTunes to play music, it's actually much easier than that, and doesn't require any other software.

In iTunes, click on the Airplay icon next to the volume control, click "Multiple" and select the devices you wish to play through.

[image: iTunes Airplay]

Comment: Doesn't work for me and no longer looks like this. There is no "multiple" option anymore and the moment I tried to add anything not my airplay TV the airplay TV gets disconnected

Answer (score 8):

Try using the midi setup application included in OS X it can let you group sound outputs together. You just need to create a new multi-output group with the + button.
[image: image of audio/midi setup]

Comment: At least in Sierra multi-output and aggregate sound outputs don't provide AirPlay as an available output device, so this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of doing this is by using a 3rd party app "Airfoil". But if you use Airfoil you will have to use 2 different applications to play the music (eg. Spotify will stream to AirPlay while Chrome plays on Mac). I know Airfoil isn't the fix you're asking for but it's the closest solution you are likely to find.

https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a rectangular Airplay button on Itunes, but if I click the circular airplay icon to the right of volume bar, I get multiple options to redirect the audio output, similar to the picture in the accepted answer (MacOS 10.14.6, ITunes 12.9.5.5).

However, as is mentioned in the comment to the accepted answer, my Airplay broadcast disconnects as soon as I try to change the audio output in ITunes.

I was, however, able to direct audio from VLC to my built-in speakers without affecting the Airplay output.  I can listen to music on the computer while Airplay broadcasting TV to another room.